# An easier of keeping data in the text fields in php if an error statement occurs

Tags: php, html

I have a simple xhtml form with textboxes asking the user for their name, id, address etc. I have to use php to validate the data. For example in the ID field exactly 6 numerical values are allowed, if thats not the case, it shows an error to the user asking them to fix it. What i want do is, when the user clicks submit with the incorrect data, i want to keep the data in the field when the error shows up. I am currently doing that by:-

```
 <td><label for="customerid">*Customer ID: </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="
<?php if(($_POST['customerid'] != $id) || ($_POST["customerfname"] != $fname) 
||    ($_POST["customerlname"] != $lname)){echo $_POST['customerid'];} ?>"

id="customerid" name="customerid"/>
```

I have just been modyifying that statement for all textboxes but as you can imagine it will get a little complicated if i have to do that for 10 boxes. i was wondering if it was an easier way to do this.

**bold** UPDATED

```
<td> <select name="state" id="state"  value="<?php echo (isset($_POST["state"]) ?  : ''); ?>"> 
    <option value="--">--</option>
    <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
    <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
    <option value="NT">NT</option>
    <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
    <option value="SA">SA</option>
 </select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<input type="text" name="customerid" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['customerid']) ? $_POST['customerid'] : ''); ?>">
```

**Update - run your checks before the form is re-generated**

```
<?php

if(($_POST['customerid'] != $id) || ($_POST["customerfname"] != $fname) || ($_POST["customerlname"] != $lname))
{
    // do nothing
}
else
{
    $_POST['customerid'] = '';
}

?>

<input type="text" name="customerid" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['customerid']) ? $_POST['customerid'] : ''); ?>">
```

Comment: this statement leaves the input in the box if it is valid, is there anyway to counter that?

Comment: Why would you remove **any** data at all if some of it is invalid? Submitting a form should be an all-or-nothing process. Maybe I just don't understand your scheme but I think a user would feel very frustrated if they had to re-enter valid data.

Comment: thats what i am saying, if any of the data is invalid, the invalid data should stay in the boxes after submitting the form but if it isnt, the data should disappear when submit is clicked. I should probably mention that its a SELF POST form so it refreshes to itself.

Comment: Yes I understand that but from a user-experience perspective that is a terrible idea. Please see my update though.

Comment: i know what you mean, personally i woudnt do it like that but since its part of an assignment, i have to adhere to the rules. Thanks for your help so far. Is there anyway possible to do this for a select drop down list?

Comment: Of course it's possible, if you can show what you've tried so far then I can guide you.

Comment: okay i have updated the question. Thats what i am doing currently but it  doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: A `<select>` tag needs `<option>` tags inside of it. Please read these resources and feel free to try again: http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms11.htm https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: I know, i just havnt added as my select is really long and didnt think i was necessary. I talked to my teacher and got him to change the part where the textboxes need to be blank if everything is valid, so thanks for that

Comment: I wasn't expecting you to add all of the `<option>` tags, just 3 or 4 so that I could help you through the PHP issue, feel free to update your question if you would still like some help =)

Comment: added the options, i tried using 'selected' but im pretty sure im using it wrong lol

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can do here either separately, or in some combination:

1. Submit the form via AJAX
2. Do validation in Javascript before handing it off to the server (this will catch most of the errors a user might encounter)
3. Keep the submitted values in the `$_SESSION` array and just echo them into the field if they are set. ex `<input type='text' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['myVal'] || '';?>'></input>`

Answer (score 0):

what are those statements?

```
$_POST['customerid'] != $id
```

you can make $fields array to store labels an $errors array to place errors in and then just

```
<?php $fields = array ('customerId' => '*CustomerID'); ?>

<?php  // validation   ?>

<?php foreach($fields as $name => $label): ?>

<td><label for="<?php echo $name ?>"><?php echo $label?>: </label></td>
<td>
<input type="text" value="" id="<?php echo $name ?>" name="<?php echo $name ?>">

<?php if(isset($errors[$name])): ?>
  <?php echo $errors[$name] ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</td>


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You could also add html validation to the form to stop the user from submitting empty form by adding "required" attribute to inputs (`<input required ... >`) or the "pattern" attribute